# Use of Aspect Oriented programming

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am new in the use of Spring and especially here with Spring AOP.

I would like to send a notification when a user is created.

I have a UserManager class with a createUser method.

After calling this method I would like to send the notification.

Here is the configuration file :

```
<bean id="userManager" class="event.UserManager" />

<bean id="notifier" class="event.ConsoleNotifier" />

<bean id="notifyAdvice" class="event.NotifierAdvice">
    <property name="notifier" ref="notifier" />
</bean>

<bean id="observerPointcut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcut">
    <property name="mappedName" value="createUser" />
</bean>

<bean id="notifierAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice" ref="notifyAdvice" />
    <property name="pointcut" ref="observerPointcut" />
</bean>
```

and finally the weaver

```
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" />
```

I want to create a UserManager object and call the createUser method to check that it is working

```
User user = new User.....
UserManager um = (UserManager) context.getBean("userManager");
um.createUser(user);
```

I have a cast exception : $Proxy4 cannot be cast to event.UserManager

I kind of understand why so my question is :

How do I instanciate a UserManager object to call the createUser method ?

Comment: Does UserManager implement an interface? If so, use `getBean` and cast to interface not the concrete class.

Comment: Otherwise, user `<property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />` for `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator`.

Comment: the proxyTargetClass thing works good.. thank you.. put it as an answer I can accept... but is it the way it has to work ?

Comment: I think you are right, it would be better to use Interface and not the proxyTargetClass value

Comment: Spring has always [recommended programming to interfaces](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-api-proxying-class), but there are situations where a class simply cannot be changed to implement an interface (legacy code, for example), so there is the option of proxying class instances that don't implement an interface, through the use of CGLIB library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `UserManager` implements an interface then program to interfaces: cast your `getBean()` call to the interface.
Otherwise, use `<property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />` for `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator`.

Spring has always [recommended programming to interfaces](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-api-proxying-class), but there are situations where a class simply cannot be changed to implement an interface (legacy code, for example), so there is the option of proxying class instances that don't implement an interface, through the use of CGLIB library. `proxyTargetClass` tells Spring to proxy that class using CGLIB, as opposed to JDK proxying through interfaces, which is the default behavior in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here are two suggestions after looking at your code.

1) If possible adapt to Spring 3.0+ which gives you annotation driven capabilities for Aspect Oriented Programming. This will make your life much more easier than the XMLs. Moreover concept wise it doesn't matter. You can use the extract of below code to fix your issue.

2) Here is an example how you can do this.

Remember Spring AOP is proxy based, which means Spring requires your beans (which need an advice) to implement an interface. At runtime a proxy implementation of the interface is generated and the advice code is embedded.

Find the code below:

```
public interface UserMgr{
    public void createUser();
}

@Component
public class UserManager implements UserMgr{
    public void createUser(){
        do something...
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class UserAspect{
    @Around("execution(public * com.*..*createUser(..))")
    public Object aroundUserCreate(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {        
        Object proceed = null;
        try {   
           do some advice work here...
        } finally {
           do some work if required...  
        }
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is a best practice for each Spring bean to implement an interface, but strictly speaking it is not necessary because Spring (and Spring AOP) can utilise CGLIB for creating dynamic proxies for non-interface types. In that case CGLIB needs to be on cla classpath though.

Comment: yeah true, I just want to make it simpler. He is new to Spring and AOP. :)